# Sortrows with multiple sorting keys in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I haven't found this answer on SO, so I am sharing it here:

Question:  How do you emulate sortrows functionality in matlab when there are multiple sorting keys?  In matlab, this looks like e.g.:

```
sortrows(x,[3,-4])
```

which sorts first by the 3rd column and then by the second column.

If you were sorting by one column, you could use `np.argsort` to find the indices of that column, and apply those indices.  But how do you do it for multiple columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is quite unwieldy and looks weird, but the cleanest thing to do is [`np.lexsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html).

```
data = np.array([[3, 0, 0, .24],
                 [4, 1, 1, .41],
                 [2, 1, 1, .63],
                 [1, 1, 3, .38]]) #imagine rows of a spreadsheet
#now do sortrows(data,[3,-4])
ix = np.lexsort((data[:, 3][::-1], data[:, 2])) 
#this yields [0, 2, 1, 3]

#note that lexsort sorts first from the last row, so sort keys are in reverse order

data[ix]
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT2: as negative inicies in python have meaning, I think they should not be used to specify descending order for the column, therefore I used here an auxiliary Descending-object.

```
import numpy as np

class Descending:
    """ for np_sortrows: sort column in descending order """
    def __init__(self, column_index):
        self.column_index = column_index

    def __int__(self):  # when cast to integer
        return self.column_index


def np_sortrows(M, columns=None):
    """  sorting 2D matrix by rows
    :param M: 2D numpy array to be sorted by rows
    :param columns: None for all columns to be used,
                    iterable of indexes or Descending objects
    :return: returns sorted M
    """
    if len(M.shape) != 2:
        raise ValueError('M must be 2d numpy.array')
    if columns is None:  # no columns specified, use all in reversed order
        M_columns = tuple(M[:, c] for c in range(M.shape[1]-1, -1, -1))
    else:
        M_columns = []
        for c in columns:
            M_c = M[:, int(c)]
            if isinstance(c, Descending):
                M_columns.append(M_c[::-1])
            else:
                M_columns.append(M_c)
        M_columns.reverse()

    return M[np.lexsort(M_columns), :]

data = np.array([[3, 0, 0, .24],
                 [4, 1, 1, .41],
                 [2, 1, 3, .25],
                 [2, 1, 1, .63],
                 [1, 1, 3, .38]])

# third column is index 2, fourth column in reversed order at index 3    
print(np_sortrows(data, [2, Descending(3)]))
```

Comment: should be fixed now

Comment: This is way more complicated than it needs to be. `my_list_or_array[::-1]` is standard in Python for getting the reverse of a list or array while maintaining its type. You can also use [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed), which is faster and easier to read. It returns an iterator.

Comment: I do actualy use it in M_columns.append(M_c[::-1]) for the descending order